# Java writing/editing a properties file

Tags: java, file

I have a really confusing problem.
I am trying to change a property in my properties file, but it just is not changing...

Here is the code:

```
package config;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

    /**
     * @author Crunchify.com
     * 
     */
    public class CrunchifyGetPropertyValues {
        String result = "";
        InputStream inputStream;

        public String getPropValues() throws IOException {

            try {
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                String propFileName = "config.properties";

                inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

                if (inputStream != null) {
                    prop.load(inputStream);
                } else {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
                }

                Date time = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

                // get the property value and print it out
                String user = prop.getProperty("user");
                String company1 = prop.getProperty("company1");
                String company2 = prop.getProperty("company2");
                String company3 = prop.getProperty("company3");
                prop.setProperty("company1", "Amazon");
                prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.properties"), null);

                // result = "Company List = " + company1 + ", " + company2 + ", " +
                // company3;
                // System.out.println(result + "\nProgram Ran on " + time + " by
                // user=" + user);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }## Heading ##
```

The code am I am specifically looking at is

```
prop.setProperty("company1", "Amazon");
prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.properties"), null);
```

For some reason my properties file won't change...

```
 #Crunchify Properties
    user=Crunchify
    company1=Google
    company2=eBay
    company3=Yahoo
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your code works for me.  The answers give below are correct as my output file was written to the working directory of the program when it was running but the input file was read as a resource from the classpath of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `getResourceAsStream(` this retrieves the file from the class path. e.g. if you have a `/home/user/resources` in your class path, this is where it looks for the file.

If you use `new FileOutputStream("config.properties")` this uses the current working directory, only as you didn't specify a directory.

In short, it is writing to the properties, just not the one you are reading.  You could write to the one in the class path provided it comes from a directory however I suggest you only write to the current work directory or a directory provided in configuration.

Comment: Oh wow, what a silly mistake. Thanks for pointing it out, my issue is now resolved.

Comment: @CCV I have done this type of mistake before, more than once. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are reading the file from one place (i.e. resources) and it might be that you are saving the file in another place (i.e. current working directory).